# Copying files from one server to another through a .NET Windows application on my local machine

Tags: c#, .net, file, copy

I have a Windows application built in C#, .NET  3.5.
One of its functionalities is to copy files from ServerA to ServerB.
The application will be run on a client machine, ClientX.

What is the most efficient command/way to do this in C# so that the files are not temporarily buffered in the ClientX machine by the application?

So the flow of the files should look like:

```
ServerA ----> ServerB
```

and NOT like:

```
ServerA ----> ClientX (temporarily buffered internally by .NET) ----> ServerB
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use the [File eXchange Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) which uses FTP to do a direct transfer from one server to another without the file ever visiting the client.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. +1 for your answer for now. And if I eventually use it, I will also mark it as an answer. Other suggestions are still welcome :)